# How do I remove old ZFS snapshots

Tags: zfs

After running updates on Ubuntu I receive a warning about my ZFS filesystem. Is there a utility or script I can use to remove old snapshots? Below is the message:

```
ERROR couldn't save system state: Minimum free space to take a snapshot and preserve ZFS performance is 20%.
Free space on pool "rpool" is 10%.
Please remove some states manually to free up space.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [zfs-prune-snapshots](https://github.com/bahamas10/zfs-prune-snapshots),
described as:

> Remove snapshots from one or more zpools that match given criteria

An example from the docs:

> Remove snapshots older than a week across all zpools
>
> ```
> zfs-prune-snapshots 1w
> ```
>
> Same as above, but with increased verbosity and without actually
> deleting any snapshots (dry-run)
>
> ```
> zfs-prune-snapshots -vn 1w
> ```

You may find more methods in the post
[How to delete all but last [n] ZFS snapshots?](https://serverfault.com/questions/340837/how-to-delete-all-but-last-n-zfs-snapshots)